# Error when I parse a Json

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, dictionary

I created a python app to parse a json API.
There is 3 endpoints and 1 of these worries me. 
The endpoint is : http://coinmarketcap.northpole.ro/history.json?coin=PCN

My code :

```
def getHistory(self, coin):
    endpoint = "history.json?year=2017&coin=PCN"
    data = urllib2.urlopen(self.url + endpoint).read()
    data = json.loads(data)['history']
    return data

def getOrder(self):
    for c in self.getCoinsList():
        res = []

        symbol = c['symbol']
        price = self.getCoinPrice(symbol)
        count = 0
        count_days = len(self.getHistory(symbol))
        for h in self.getHistory(symbol):
            if h['price']['usd'] > price:
                ++count
        percent_down = count_days / count * 100
        line = {'symbol': symbol, 'price': price, 'percent_down': percent_down}
        res.append(line)
        return res
```

When I try to get the `h['price']['usd']` I have this :

```
File "coinmarketcap.py", line 39, in getOrder
    if h['price']['usd'] > price:
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

When I do `print type(h)` it return unicode.

Comment: So you have confirmed that h is a string and the error says that string indices have to be integers. You are trying to index the string using other strings.

Comment: But I want to get h['price']['usd'], how I can do that ?

Comment: I assume `getHistory` returns a dict and you're iterating over it like this: `for h in self.getHistory(symbol)`. This gives you the dict _keys_, not _values_. Try `for h in self.getHistory(symbol).values()`.

Comment: You are treating h as a dictionary when you have confirmed it is a string. What ever json.loads(data)['history'] returns from getHistory() is not what you think it is.

Comment: @Rawing You can do the answer it's the right solution !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getHistory` returns a dict, and when you iterate over it like this:

```
for h in self.getHistory(symbol):
```

you're iterating over the dict *keys*, not *values*.

To iterate over the value instead, use

```
for h in self.getHistory(symbol).values(): # .itervalues() in python2
```

Answer (score 1):

@Pixel, I think you are assuming that `for h in self.getHistory(symbol):` returns the value of the key, which is incorrect, it returns the key.

Try saving the dictionary and fetch by key mapping, like this,

```
json_data = self.getHistory(symbol)
for h in json_data:
    if json_data[h]['price']['usd'] > price:
        ++count
```

or retrieve the values from the dictionary values, using

```
for h in self.getHistory(symbol).values():
    if h['price']['usd'] > price:
        ++count
```